# Kendo MVC Helper "Route()" Generates Wrong URL

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to define a custom Kendo grid toolbar command, using the Kendo Route() MVC helper as in

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Imports)
.Name("ImportsGrid")
.ToolBar(tb => tb.Custom().Route("DataImportData", new { tableType = DataTablesTypeEnum.MyTables, id = Model.TableName }).Text("Import Data"))
```

But the generated URL is incorrect - it ends up being the same URL as the page that contains the grid which is a clue that it couldn't find the route somehow.

However... When I use the Url.RouteUrl() method like so

```
@{ var url = Url.RouteUrl("DataImportData", new { tableType = DataTablesTypeEnum.MyTables, id = Model.TableName });}
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Imports)
        .Name("ImportsGrid")
        .ToolBar(tb => tb.Custom().Url(url).Text("Import Data"))
```

The correct URL is generated.

My route is defined like this:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DataImportData",
            url: "{controller}/{tableType}/{id}/Import",
            defaults: new { controller = "Data", action = "ImportData" },
            namespaces: new[] { "MyApp.MyNamespace" }
            );
```

Is this a known problem with Kendo or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is because the action is specified as a default and not as a parameter. If I include the action in the route data the Kendo Route() method, the route is properly matched.

```
.ToolBar(tb => tb.Custom().Route("DataImportData", new { action="ImportData", tableType = DataTableTypeEnum.MyTables, id = Model.TableName }).Text("Import Data"))
```

I also discovered that, at least in this case, I can simply use the Action method and specify the action ("ImportData") directly as in

```
.ToolBar(tb => tb.Custom().Action("ImportData", "Data", new { tableType = DataTableTypeEnum.MyTables, id = Model.TableName }).Text("Import Data"))
```

and the route is properly matched with the expected URL.